# How to retrieve all the record type and their columns i.e. metadata using NetSuite web service

Tags: c#, metadata, netsuite

I'm trying to integrate an application developed on `.NET platform` with the `NetSuite` application. I want to retrieve all the `record types` those are supported by `SuiteTalk` with their columns and other attributes.

I know `NetSuite` provides the documentation about which records are supported by them, but I want to retrieve them dynamically using the code, so that if in future anything change in those records, should automatically reflected into the code.

I'm not sure how should I move ahead. I don't see that `NetSuite` provides any service which does that.

So basically  I want to know *is there any metadata service available for NetSuite schema?* If not then what could be the alternative to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Do you understand about the relationship between SOAP and WSDL? This covers all their records and fields that are exposed via SuiteTalk. In addition the platform guide contains info on how to retrieve the metadata for all customizations (custom records and fields)

Netsuite publishes as WSDL link for every new release of SuiteTalk. The WSDL link url is available in the Netsuite help under the topic "SuiteTalk Archives". This also provides links to how to diff between different SuiteTalk versions.

Comment: I know that how to retrieve the metadata of custom record. I'm looking for the similar way for NetSuite standard record. I'm not sure how can I retrieve the records and field info from wsdl. Do I need to use reflection?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure we understand your question. I think Brett answered your question, the WSDL contains references to each schema that describe all of the standard objects.

If you are using Visual Studio for your .NET project just load the WSDL and the schemas will be included. Here is more help on how to do this in VS:

[How to use a WSDL File to create a WCF Proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945620/how-to-use-a-wsdl-file-to-create-a-wcf-proxy][1])