# What works as a Web Refence(ASMX) should work as a Service Reference(WCF), correct?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, soap

I've recently noticed that using Service References(WCF) causes problems with plain old SOAP API's. I thought that the newer more improved approach was to use Service References because WCF is more flexible and modern. Can anyone detect how I can make this work with WCF in VS2013?

It is a simple console app trying to consume RxNav (free) api

```
URL: http://mor.nlm.nih.gov/axis/services/RxNormDBService
```

After adding a "Service Reference" to the solution I entered the following code:

**Program.cs**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var client = new RxNavAPI.DBManagerClient();

    try
    {
        var matches = client.getDrugs("aspirin");

        foreach (var conceptGroup in matches)
        {
            foreach (var concept in conceptGroup.rxConcept)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Name: {0}, Syn: {1}", concept.STR, concept.SY));
            }
        }

        client.close();
    }
    catch (TimeoutException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Timeout occurred while accessing RxNav API");
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        throw;
    }
}
```

**App.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="RxNormDBServiceSoapBinding" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://mor.nlm.nih.gov/axis/services/RxNormDBService"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RxNormDBServiceSoapBinding"
                contract="RxNavAPI.DBManager" name="RxNormDBService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

One thing that I have noticed is when added as a **Web Reference** the client is called like:

```
var client = new RxNavAPI.DBManagerService();
```

while when using **Service Reference** it is like:

```
var client = new RxNavAPI.DBManagerClient();
```

*EDIT*: The error I am receiving is

> System.InvalidOperationException : "RPC Message
>   getProprietaryInformationRequest1 in operation
>   getProprietaryInformation1 has an invalid body name
>   getProprietaryInformation. It must be getProprietaryInformation1"

Comment: What issues are you seeing?  If the only issue that you're seeing is the difference between `DBManagerService` and `DBManagerClient`?  WCF appends `Client` to the services you add via add service reference.  It's been a while since I've done ASMX, but perhaps ASMX added `Service` instead of `Client`.

Comment: In general, it should work, but there may, of course, be specific situations where it won't work. Create a separate question with specific details, and you'll probably get some good answers.

Comment: Tim/John I've added the error to the original post. I don't get this message when using a Web Reference.

Comment: John, I agree it general it should work but it doesn't. This isn't the only soap-based api that I've configured with Service Reference and it doesn't work. Almost everyone seems to say go with the older Web Reference as it's simpler and less error prone.

Answer (score 0):

Awesome!
 @John Saunders answering everywhere. 
This is the same issue noted over 5 years ago. [WCF: Svcutil generates invalid client proxy, Apache AXIS Web Service, overload operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799365/wcf-svcutil-generates-invalid-client-proxy-apache-axis-web-service-overload-o)

Now I'm having the same issue and there is still no fix, only workarounds for this.

Comment: Just never use Service Reference for SOAP-based APIs.