# calling a soap service from C#

Tags: c#, php, web-services, soap

I have working PHP code which calls a SOAP service and it works. Its as follows:

```
<?php
try
{
    $client = new SoapClient(null, array(
        'location' => "http://108-168-196-91.mycitrixdemo.net/zdm/services/EveryWanDevice?wsdl",
        'uri' => "http://zdemo2.zenprise.com",
        'login' => "Admin",
        'password'=> "XXXXX"));

    $properties=$client->getDeviceProperties("XXXXXXXX",null);

    for($i=0;$i<count($properties);$i++) {
        printf ("name: %s, value: %s\n" , $properties[$i]->name, $properties[$i]->value);
    }
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    print_r($e); exit;
}
?>
```

I need to access the same service from C#. I have tried adding `Service Reference` to `http://108-168-196-91.mycitrixdemo.net/zdm/services/EveryWanDevice?wsdl` and this added the following section in my app.config.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="EveryWanDeviceSoapBinding" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://108-168-196-91.mycitrixdemo.net/zdm/services/EveryWanDevice"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="EveryWanDeviceSoapBinding"
            contract="ServiceReference1.DeviceService" name="EveryWanDevice" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I am now provided with the proxy classes but I dont know how to set them up so I could call this service.

I am doing it as follows in C#:

```
DeviceService srv = new DeviceServiceClient();//
srv.authenticateUser(new authenticateUserRequest("Admin", "XXXXXX"));

var devices = srv.getDeviceProperties(new getDevicePropertiesRequest("99000067296308", null));
```

But the `srv.authenticateUser` line throws the following exception:

```
RPC Message getDeploymentHistoRequest1 in operation getDeploymentHisto1 has an invalid body name getDeploymentHisto. It must be getDeploymentHisto1
```

I have no idea what does this error mean. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to using a WCF reference versus a standard service reference.

Take a look at [WCF: Svcutil generates invalid client proxy, Apache AXIS Web Service, overload operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799365/wcf-svcutil-generates-invalid-client-proxy-apache-axis-web-service-overload-o) for further discussion.

In short, use <kbd>Add Web Reference</kbd> on the Advanced page of Add Service Reference:

[image: Add Web Reference]

Answer (score 1):

To me this error looks like an issue with generating your proxy file. You probably want to re-proxy by using [svcutil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to make sure your proxy file is being generated correctly. In your case, the command in your Visual Studio Developer Command tool would look like so...

```
svcutil.exe /language:cs /out:Proxies.cs /config:output.config [service url]
```

It also doesn't look like you're establishing a secure session in the first Place. Change your binding to the following...

```
<binding name="EveryWanDeviceSoapBinding" 
         closeTimeout="00:01:00" 
         openTimeout="00:01:00" 
         receiveTimeout="00:10:00" 
         sendTimeout="00:01:00" 
         allowCookies="false" 
         bypassProxyOnLocal="false" 
         hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" 
         maxBufferSize="6553666" 
         maxBufferPoolSize="524288" 
         maxReceivedMessageSize="6553666" 
         messageEncoding="Text" 
         textEncoding="utf-8" 
         transferMode="Buffered" 
         useDefaultWebProxy="true">
    <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" 
                   proxyCredentialType="Basic" 
                   realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" 
                 algorithmSuite="Default" />
    </security>
</binding>
```

The vast majority of that are just basic defaults for a service binding. The `security` part is what should let you establish a secure connection to the service like so...

```
var srv = new DeviceServiceClient();

srv.ClientCreditials.UserName.UserName = "Admin";
srv.ClientCreditials.UserName.Password = "XXXXX";
```

Finally you can call the `getDeviceProperties` method with your arguments and get some sort of a response back.